# Pandas cumcount() when np.nan exists

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, np.nan],
                   [1, np.nan, 3],
                   [2, 2, 3],
                   [3, 4, np.nan]])
```

when I `groupby` all the 3 columns and then `cumcount`, as expected, all the returned value should be 0 because there's only one row in each group, but what I get is:

```
In [34]: df.groupby([0, 1, 2]).cumcount()
Out[34]:
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    2
dtype: int64
```

and we can see that all the rows with `nan` value are grouped into one group, so is this a bug or something that I don't know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`groupby` omit `NaN`s rows so possible solution should be replace them to value which not exist in data, e.g. `-1`.

Btw, `cumcount` seems create with omited rows separated group.

```
for i, df in df.groupby([0, 1, 2]):
    print (df)
   0    1    2
2  2  2.0  3.0
```

---

```
print (df.fillna(-1).groupby([0, 1, 2]).cumcount())
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: thank you @jezrael, so do you mean that groups with nan value are omited by groupby? but when I execute `len(df.groupby([0, 1, 2]).groups)`, `4` is returned, do you know what the problem is?

Comment: @WoodsChen - Hard question, really. Maybe it depends of function, if use `groupby.sum` it omit it.

Comment: @WoodsChen - Maybe in `cumcount` it is different, [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#na-and-nat-group-handling) get only general answer.