# Pandas CumCount on GroupBy object with NaN column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, data-science

So I have df with 'col2' populated with NaN values.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'],
              data=[['a', float('nan'), 'c'],
                    ['f', float('nan'), 'g'],
                    ['a', float('nan'), 'k'],
                    ['a', float('nan'), 'r']])
```

then I am grouping on ['col1', 'col2']

```
grpby = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])
```

The groups I see in grpby.groups are:

```
{('a', nan): [0, 2, 3], ('f', nan): [1]}
```

When I do a groupcount I get unexpected result:

```
grpby.cumcount()
```

results in:

```
(0, 0) (1, 1) (2, 2) (3, 3)
```

What I expect to see is:

```
(0, 0) (1, 0) (2, 1) (3, 2)
```

I am able to get this result adding dropna=False to the groupBy.
I don't understand how groupby and cumcount work together. Reading the documentation if dropna is True by default which means columns/rows with NaN values are dropped and not included when grouping is done.
Why am I getting all rows counted as a single group? Even if values in 'col1' are different I still get this behavior. If I have different values in 'col1' and NaNs in 'col2' and I groupby on ['col1', 'col2'] then I do CumCount on that I still get (0, 0) (1, 1) (2, 2) (3, 3), when in fact I expect it to be (0, 0) (1, 0) (2, 0) (3, 0).
Can someone help me understand?

Comment: `df.groupby(['col1']).cumcount()` or `df.fillna(0).groupby(['col1', 'col2']).cumcount()`....due to the presence of `nan's` in 'col2' column you are not getting that you are expected to see

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52053091/pandas-cumcount-when-np-nan-exists

Comment: @AnuragDabas  I can't use df.fillna(0) because I don't want to modify the data in the dataframe. I also know that the main cause is the NaN values in 'col2', what I don't understand is why dropna=False is dealing with that, since the default behavior of dropna=True means that NaN rows should be dropped, but actually aren't? I am missing something.